# How to compile Matlab script for specified Matlab Runtime (MCR)

Tags: matlab, compilation, matlab-compiler, mcc

I have Matlab 2010a installed on my machine, and MCR 7.6 installed on client's machine.
I try to figure out how can I compile my code for MCR 7.6.
Currently mcc comlipes scripts for 7.9 ( which has been installed with Matlab).
Does mcc has any arguments for it, or parameters in cfg file?
(or anything else)

Answer (score 3):

From the [MCR help](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/compiler/f12-999353.html) file:

> The MCR is version-specific. You must run your applications with the version of the MCR associated with the version of MATLAB Compiler with which it was created. For example, if you compiled an application using version 4.10 (R2009a) of MATLAB Compiler, users who do not have MATLAB installed must have version 7.10 of the MCR installed. Use mcrversion to return the version number of the MCR.

Could you have your client install MCR 7.9 on their computer?

Comment: No, only 7.6.  This is the issue, I have to compile for MCR 7.6, but seems that mcc doestn't have option for this. (Which is kinda silly).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. As Doresoom mentioned, get the client to install MCR 7.9 on their machine.  (You can package the MCR with your files.  Open `deploytool` and click Package.)
2. Use an older version of MATLAB to compile your code.

Comment: Thanks. In my case (2) is the only option.